# Execute exe from java and assign the output to a variable

Tags: java

I have a getlocation.exe file which gives the file path of application when I run it from the command prompt in windows.
I'm looking to execute this command from Java code and assign the output to string variable.

eg: if the output of the command is C:/application/home
I need this path to be assigned in a string variable

Comment: Read your process's InputStream to capture any output from its standard out. This has been asked and answered many times on this and other sites.

Comment: [For example](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+capture+output+from+an+exe)

Comment: closing this 1251039